# Mask effect below pop-up box using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I convert any div on my webpages to pop-up box by adding a class, `turnIntoOverlay` , to the div. (See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVvhF/1/))

```
.turnIntoOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 60px;
    max-width: 680px;
    z-index: 80;
    border: 6px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Now when the pop up is displayed I also want to create a mask that puts up a faded layer(or mask) to the rest other page elements that appear below popup box. To create this mask, I resorted to pure css approach using psuedo selectors, so that the mask is shown/hidden simply when a popup box( a `turnIntoOverlay` element) is visible. I added the following css:

```
.turnIntoOverlay:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Everything works fine except that the mask appears on the pop up as well even when I keep the z-index lower than of popup. Also to my surprise, it works  only when `z-index=-1`. 
Can you please suggest how to rectify this ?

## **See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVvhF/1/) here**

Comment: How are you adding the class `turnIntoOverlay` to the `<div/>`s?

Comment: somtimes client side via javascript, aometimes it is there by default

Comment: I see. If you add the class via javascript, why not simply having a global `<div id="overlay"/>` and while adding the `.turnIntoOverlay` additonally add a class `.show` or something to the `#overlay`? This would simplify things a lot I think.

Comment: as I said it is *only sometimes* added via javascript & sometimes it is there by default on page or received as part of ajax response. I did thought of using js approach prior to css approach but that was making things too complicated..

Comment: do you see any issues  ? would  you like to comment on  solution by Gareth ?

Comment: No, if you can live with overwriting the `background-color` and do not need the `border` to have the desired color, it is the perfect solution without the necessity of changing the html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is to use both `:before` and `:after` to solve your problem:

```
.turnIntoOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    top: 60px;
    max-width: 680px;
    border: 6px solid #BBB;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding:10px;
    z-index: 80;
}

.turnIntoOverlay:before {
    content: "";
    background-color: skyblue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0.4;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.turnIntoOverlay:after{
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVvhF/5/)**

Comment: do you have anything to say about the cross browser compatibility of this css approach for mask effect ?

Comment: This applies to all solutions using `:after`: One issue is that IE8 and below don't know `opacity`. You could use `-ms-filter`, but sadly IE applies filters only on elements that have layout, and the pseudo `:after` has no layout.

Comment: @Gareth Cornish: There is an issue with this solution. When there is a scrollbar on the overlay div, for the overflowed markup within it, the scrollbar is visible but not scrollable by mousepress+move, though works with mouse scroll wheel. See JSfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/CVvhF/18/

Comment: Do you have any fix for this ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Understanding_z-index/The_stacking_context). The `:after` content can not be below it's parent, except if the parent would be out of the stacking context which in your case is no option. `z-index: -1` works because it's a special case and has priority over the parents content. That's why it does not effect the text, but effects background and border. See the list on [Stacking Contexts](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking). Your `:after { z-index: -1 }` is nr. 2 in the list.

Your only option would be using an additional wrapper:

```
<div class="turnIntoOverlay"><div>this div is convertible to pop up!<input/></div></div>
```

moving your current styles for `.turnIntoOverlay` to `.turnIntoOverlay > div` and applying the overlay to the outer div with a positive `z-index`:

```
.turnIntoOverlay:after {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CVvhF/3/).

Unfortunately IE8 and below are buggy on that. Also they do not know `opacity` and using `-ms-filter` does not work on elements without layout like pseudo classes `:before` and `:after` are.

---

Of course, if you'd use an additional wrapper anyway, you could just give the other wrapper the `background-color`. No need for `:after` then:

```
.turnIntoOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: skyblue; /* for old browsers */
    background-color: rgba(135, 206, 235, 0.4);
}
```

Compared to the pseudo class approach, this includes a little fix for IE8 and below. Can be made even better by using a transparent png which is applied to IE. With that, it looks quite the same in every browser (after IE6 I would say).

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w4RWk/).

Comment: Thanks Linus, although your proposed solution works but I don't like adding an additional `div` inside `div.turnIntoOverlay`. Moreover I would need to take care to place 1 & only 1 div inside `div.turnIntoOverlay`. Solution by @Gareth seems to probably overcome these situations.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the `position: fixed` from `.turnIntoOverlay` and now it works.

Comment: thanks but this wont be a solution for me because I *need* fixed positioning.

Comment: Except that it's not a popup any more.